# Update table column to make it primary key

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have a table

```
Name Age Sex id
A     12  m   
B     13  f  
C     11  f 
....
```

I want the table to look like this to make id a primary key

```
 Name Age Sex id
 A     12  m   1
 B     13  f   2 
 C     11  f   3
    ....
```

Comment: You cant do this with update query you will have to do it with alter query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE  `test` ADD  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing the column attribute you can use alter command

```
alter table tblName
change id id number(10) NOT Null primary key;
```

you can auto increment the values as:

```
alter table tblName
change id id number(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use this:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD `columnName` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table tbl change id id int primary key auto_increment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do this via two way

1.Sql Query

```
ALTER TABLE `tble` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

2.If you have access of table then insert a field name id and set  attribute `index` => `Primary` and `check the Auto Increment attribute`

thanks